# Workaround for Item assignment not supported in dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to convert my code base from numpy array to dask because  my numpy arrays are exceeding the `Memory Error` limit. But, I come to know that the feature of mutable arrays are not yet implemented in `dask arrays` so I am getting 
`NotImplementedError: Item assignment with <class 'tuple'> not supported`
Is there any workaround for my code below-

```
for i, mask in enumerate(masks):
    bounds = find_boundaries(mask, mode='inner')
    X2, Y2 = np.nonzero(bounds)
    X2 = da.from_array(X2, 'auto')
    Y2 = da.from_array(Y2, 'auto')
    xSum = (X2.reshape(-1, 1) - X1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
    ySum = (Y2.reshape(-1, 1) - Y1.reshape(1, -1)) ** 2
    #Failing on below line
    distMap[:,i] = da.sqrt(xSum + ySum).min(axis=0)

    break
```

I also tried computing all other computations in dask and using `distMap` as a numpy array but still got the `Memory Error`.
Any workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can construct many dask arrays and then use `da.concatenate` or `da.stack` to merge them into a single dask array?